# Is the Architect watching Neo right from the beginning?

Tags: the-matrix

While [Neo is being interrogated, we see the same panel of monitors](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4D7cPH7DHgA) watching him, as those in the Architect's room.

Is this a hint that the Architect is watching Neo right from the beginning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [Behind the Scenes of The Matrix: Reloaded](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B-89iEMgoCs&feature=youtu.be&t=9m28s) documentary, we have the following exposition from John Gaeta, the film's VFX Supervisor regarding the monitors in the Architect's chamber.

The Architect might not have been the one watching, but it's definitively the same room.

> *"Basically it's a scene in which Neo meets the architect of the Matrix.
>   **It is a place that we've actually seen once before, in the first
>   movie, but only a little glimpse of it. It's implied that he was the
>   one watching Neo during that interrogation."***

Answer (score 10):

Whether the Architect does observe Neo (excellent question, btw.) is hard to say, but the monitors are hardly an indication. The Architect most certainly doesn't require cameras to see what's going on in the Matrix. Additionally, you cannot observe a room by putting a monitor in that room (monitors simply don't work this way).

So regarding your question whether the *monitors* are an indication of the Architect watching Neo: No. However, this doesn't mean he's not.

Comment: Well, yes, I understand that the Architect doesn't *need* monitors or anything. I'm just wondering if that was a hint for the audience, that "someone" out there is watching.

Comment: @Eelvex: Yes, I got that. Perhaps somebody has more information, but I doubt there is more behind these monitors than just the visual effects. Unless there is an official statement regarding this, it will be highly argumentative.

Answer (score 6):

I always thought that the monitors were more a metaphor for what the Architect was *monitorizing*, rather than just conventional screens.

Therefore, yes, the Architect was watching Neo from the very beginning.

Comment: This seems like a valid interpretation to me. The monitors are like the Architect's calling card/family crest/symbolic representation or what have you.

Comment: *monitorizating*, seriously? :)